# Execute block code in order in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I try to load datasource for UITableView from server and it could takes a few second. My problems is asynchronous between datasource and UITableView content and of course i get an exception.

```
[self loadingDataSource]; //could take few second
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

The result of above code is the blank screen. I have discovered that when i loading DataSource in first statement, the second statement did not wait the first do complete and execute before Datasource loaded. So i try to use GCD to resolve

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self loadingDataSource]; //could take few second
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

But it still not work...

I found some other ways, for examples, using Dispatch Semaphores to wait the Loading DataSource statement complete, and after that, do the next statement. But i dont know, is it suitable for my situation.

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Could you help me? Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a completion block to your `loadingDataSource` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loadingDataSource:^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}

- (void)loadingDataSource:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Load data source
        if (completion)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), completion);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // switch to a background thread and perform your expensive operation
   [self loadingDataSource]; 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // switch back to the main thread to update your UI
     [self.tableView reloadData];

    });
});
```